# Python 3.7.3 Can't append last element of sequence into new list

Tags: python

In my code, I idea is like this:

In sequence [5,1,2,4,3] where this sequence is in non-strictly increasing order, I want to append the element that are increasing into another list.

In this case, the return list should be [1,2,4]

But I get [1,2]

My code is like this:

```
def max_increase(seq):
    list1 = []
    index = 0
    for index in range(len(seq)-1):
        if seq[index] < seq[index + 1]:
            list1.append(seq[index])
            index = index + 1
        else:
            pass
    return list1
```

I think the function didn't reach the last element in the sequence, but I don't how to fix this.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: In your provided example, the last comparison will be between 4 and 3.  4 is not less than 3 so it won't be added to the new list.  Also, the for loop is already incrementing the index so you don't need the `index = index + 1` line

Answer (score 1):

seq = [5,1,2,4,3]

def max_increase(seq):

```
list1 = []
list1.append(seq[0])

for index in range(1,len(seq)-1):
    list1.append(seq[index])
    
    if list1[0] > list1[1] :
        del list1[0]
    
    elif list1[len(list1) - 2] < list1[len(list1) - 1]:
        pass
    
    else :
        del list1[len(list1) - 1]
return list1
```

max_increase(seq)

Here's your answer, but this code only works for one increasing line only. You will understand when you run the code. If you want to append multiple elements like seq = [1,2,3,1,2,3] you will have to add more conditions before the del command at else. Just think like a bot and all the cases and you will find your answer.